# how do I trigger an Item renderer create children

Tags: actionscript-3, flex3

I have a TileList with a custom item renderer.
I need to change the children of the ItemRenderer when the dataprovider changes for the TileList.
Currently,

```
override protected function createChildren():void{
```

Works fine with the inital data, but when the data changes to a different structure I need to recreate the children somehow.
I image there has to be a way to listen to the TileList for a data change from inside the item renderer, but how? Or is that even the best route to go?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

maybe this will do the job :

```
override public function set data( value : Object ) : void 
{
    super.data = value;
   // things to happend when data is changed ...

}
```

aswell maybe updateDisplayList() shall need to be overrided aswell to match the changes with the visual components ( if there is ).

Comment: I fixed this awhile back. Turns out I did try overriding the set data method. It didn't work. What did work was directly calling createChildren form the commitProperties if the structure didn't match the data. But since nobody else answered I will check you off so this is closed

Comment: owww ... no no ... dont check it. just set your answer and accept it :)